# Android: BitmapFactory returning java.io.FileNotFoundException error, even though image is saved to external storage

Tags: java, android, image, save

I am trying to make an app in which the user can take a picture to attach to a post. For the image capturing, saving and handling part I was following the official developer guide (using their code snippets). I have no problem with taking the picture and saving it to external storage (I have found the pictures on my hard drive), but when I need to access the file for displaying the image in the view (or for starting a media scanner intent), I get an error indicating that the file was not found.

Here are some parts of my code:

File creation:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Image capture intent:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}
```

Displaying small image:

```
private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = 30;
    int targetH = 50;

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    img_added.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Adding image to gallery:

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

And then when I run the app, after taking the picture I get this in logcat:

```
E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20150731_114600_153874160.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I set the permission to write to external storage in the manifest and I can see the pictures saved to my storage, so the file exists. I was really just doing everything according to the official guide, so I have no idea what is going wrong. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I have changed the line

mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();

to

mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();

so the createImageFile() function now looks like this:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

This solved my problem with displaying the image, but the photo still does not appear in my gallery. When I log the value of the URI passed to the media scan intent, I get this:

file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20150731_135706_153874160.jpg

Could this be the problem (although I get it from the image file with Uri.fromFile method, so this should be a proper URI)? Or what else could cause the problem?

Comment: why do you use "file:" prefix in: "file:" + ... ?

Comment: Well, it was suggested in the official Android developer guide to use with ACTION_VIEW intents, so I thought it was important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line

```
mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
```

to

```
mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Thanks, that really solved the image displaying problem! (First I tried to split off the "file:" part in the setPic function only, but for some reason it still got passed on with it). However, the photo still doesn't appear in my Pictures gallery, any idea about that?